# How to sent JSON value from Fragment to module?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I  have responsed `JSONObject` from API and i tried to send the response to the module using setter then to the `Recyclerview` adapter but its not working

This is my fragment

```
public class ListViewActivityFragment extends Fragment {
List<AppShowModule> appShowModule;
RecyclerView AppRecyclerView;
List<AppShowModule> GetDataAdapter1;


RecyclerView.LayoutManager AppRecyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter AppRecyclerViewadapter;
String jsonUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json";
TextView text;
Context context;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
public ListViewActivityFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    appShowModule = new ArrayList<>();
    AppRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById( R.id.AppRecyclerView );
    text = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    AppRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( AppRecyclerViewlayoutManager );
    JsonAppShowData();}

public void JsonAppShowData() {
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray( "entry" );
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject( i ).getJSONObject("im:name");
                    AppShowModule appShowModule111 = new AppShowModule();
                    String name = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("im:name").getString("label").toString();
                    text.setText(name);
                    appShowModule111.setAppName((name));}
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e( "LOG", error.toString() );
        }
    } );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( getContext() );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    AppRecyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1,this);
    AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(AppRecyclerViewadapter);
}
}
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

List<AppShowModule> getDataAdapter;
Context MContext;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<AppShowModule> getDataAdapter, ListViewActivityFragment context){

    super();

    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.appitem, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}



@Override


public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)

{
    final AppShowModule getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);
    holder.NameTextView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getAppName());
    Picasso.with(context).load(getDataAdapter1.getAppImageUrl()).into(holder.imgPost);

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView NameTextView;
    public ImageView imgPost;
    LinearLayout lnrLayout;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);


        NameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        imgPost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
        lnrLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lnrLayout);





    }


  }
  }
```

and this is my module

```
   public class AppShowModule
 {
  private String appName;
  private String appImageUrl;
  public String getAppName() {
      return appName;}
  public void setAppName(String appName) {
      this.appName = appName;}
public String getAppImageUrl() {
    return appImageUrl;}
public void setAppImageUrl(String appImageUrl) {
    this.appImageUrl = appImageUrl;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo are creating the AppShowModule appShowModule111 = new AppShowModule(); Object but you never populated your adaapter with that object. Your JsonObjectRequest onResponse() should look like this;

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray( "entry" );
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject( i ).getJSONObject("im:name");
                AppShowModule appShowModule111 = new AppShowModule();
                String name = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("im:name").getString("label").toString();
                text.setText(name);
                appShowModule111.setAppName((name));
                GetDataAdapter1.add(appShowModule111);
            }
            AppRecyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1,ListViewActivityFragment.this);
            AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(AppRecyclerViewadapter);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }}
```

Comment: thank you but (GetDataAdapter1,this) cannot be applied !

Comment: try AppRecyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, ListViewActivityFragment.this);

Comment: thank you very much its working but now in the recycler view just one item is display but i have a 50 ! why this showing just a one ?

Comment: please check this question with full details 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454844/how-to-parse-json-array-inside-another-json-array-and-display-the-clicked-item)