# How to parse JSON Array inside another JSON Array and display the Clicked item

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-recyclerview, picasso

hello i have this Json Data [a link](https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json)

and i parsing it like that

[image]

when i click into the image i want to parsing the JsonArray for the image to piccaso in recycler view  like this ,

[image]

but i get all image like this picture

[image]

how i can solve this problem and get just the images for the item which i clicked ???

this is my module :

```
public class AppShowModule
 {
private List<String> Allimage = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getAllimage() {
    return Allimage;}
public void setAllimage(List<String> allimage) {
    Allimage = allimage;}
```

this is my Fragment

```
public class ImageListFragment extends Fragment {

List<AppShowModule> appShowModules;
List<AppShowModule> imagesModule;
RecyclerView AppRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter imageRecyclerViewadapter;
List<String> imageUrls;
String feedKey = "feed";
String entryKey = "entry";
String imageKey = "im:image";
String labelKey = "label";
String jsonUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json";
RequestQueue requestQueue;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public ImageListFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_list, container, false);
}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageRecyclerView);
    imagesModule = new ArrayList<>();
    appShowModules = new ArrayList<>();
    imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonAppShowData();
}
public void JsonAppShowData() {
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray( entryKey );
                AppShowModule appShowModule = new AppShowModule();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray imageArray = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray(entryKey).getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(imageKey);
                    for (int j = 0; j < imageArray.length(); j++) {
                        String image = imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString(labelKey).toString();
                        imageUrls.add(image);
                        appShowModule.setAllimage(imageUrls);
                        appShowModules.add(appShowModule);}}
                imageRecyclerViewadapter = new ImageListAdapter(appShowModules,getContext(),imageUrls);
                AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageRecyclerViewadapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e( "LOG", error.toString() );
        }
    } );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( getContext() );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager( getContext().getApplicationContext(),3);
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);    }}
```

and this is the Recycler adapter

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<AppShowModule> appShowModules;
List<String> imageUrl;


Context context;
public ImageListAdapter(List<AppShowModule> appShowModules, Context context ,List<String>imageUrls
){
    super();
    this.imageUrl =imageUrls;
    this.appShowModules = appShowModules;
    this.context = context;}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.imagelayout, parent,false );
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( v );
    return viewHolder;}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl.get(position)).into(holder.appImage);
}
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageUrl.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView appImage;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        appImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.appImage);


    }}}
```

and this is the activity that have the image view where click

```
public class ListViewDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView AppImage;
TextView AppName,AppArtist,AppContentType,AppRights,AppCategory,AppRealseDate,AppSammary;
ImageButton AppLink;
Context context;
public ListViewDetailsFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view_details, container, false);}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppImage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    AppName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textname);
    AppArtist = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textartest);
    AppContentType = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textcontent);
    AppRights = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textrights);
    AppCategory = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textCategory);
    AppRealseDate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textRelease);
    AppSammary = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textSummary);
    AppLink = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    String name = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_name");
    final String image = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_image");
    String artist = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_artist");
    String contentType = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_ContentType");
    String rights = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_Rights");
    String category = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_Category");
    String realse = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_ReleaseDate");
    final String link = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_link");
    String sammary = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("App_summary");
    AppName.setText(name);
    AppArtist.setText(artist);
    AppContentType.setText(contentType);
    AppRights.setText(rights);
    AppCategory.setText(category);
    AppRealseDate.setText(realse);
    AppSammary.setText(sammary);
    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(AppImage);
    AppLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    WebView.class);
            intent.putExtra("App_link", link);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);}});
    AppImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String id = (String) view.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), ImageList.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The json data has links to three different sized images, it looks to me like you are requesting that all three images are fetched.  If you don't want all three, just select the size you want (index 0, 1 or 2) and pull that image only.

```
JSONArray imageArray = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray(entryKey).getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(imageKey);
for (int j = 0; j < imageArray.length(); j++) {
   String image = imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString(labelKey).toString();
   imageUrls.add(image);
   ...
}
```

Sample Data:

```
"im:image":[  
               {  
                  "label":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple20/v4/87/35/82/87358231-ce91-3d14-b306-95888c23db3c/mzl.gdgtivnk.png/53x53bb-85.png",
                  "attributes":{  
                     "height":"53"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "label":"http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple20/v4/87/35/82/87358231-ce91-3d14-b306-95888c23db3c/mzl.gdgtivnk.png/75x75bb-85.png",
                  "attributes":{  
                     "height":"75"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "label":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple20/v4/87/35/82/87358231-ce91-3d14-b306-95888c23db3c/mzl.gdgtivnk.png/100x100bb-85.png",
                  "attributes":{  
                     "height":"100"
                  }
               }
```

**Update 9/13/2016**

Based on what I think you are after, I still think your problem is in your nested for loop in the `jsonAppShowData()` method.  Though you do appear to pass some sort of ID extra in from the previous activity, I don't see you filtering on that item ID anywhere in the for loop.  You need to restrict the outer for loop to only the item you wish to show.

For the image scaling issue, it may either be how your layout is setup or you can try some of the Picasso [resize calls](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit).

Comment: Thank u for answer .. i need three image for the application which i click in it .. but when i click in the image view ! I got all image for all application

Comment: please check this question with full details 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454844/how-to-parse-json-array-inside-another-json-array-and-display-the-clicked-item)

Comment: thank you for your answer but how to send ID ? and where should i bot the id ???? plz answer me ! or hope to tell me with details what i should do !

Comment: @Gray Bak  please answer

Comment: The ID seems to be passed to the `ImageList.class` activity, but not to the fragment.  There is no source for the Activity, so I can't tell you.